# Google calendar from Django

Tags: django, google-calendar-api

I have a monthly schedule what is changing very often. I want to link it with google calendar to see schedule changing there.
What is the best way to do that? Generate CSV file?
I want to let google calendar auto update it.

Comment: Are you looking to have the data dumped into your django db, or are you looking for front-end only functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used it, but you might find the [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html) useful. It says one of the languages it supports is python, so you should be able to use it with Django.